# All user commits across different branches

Tags: git, github, commit, git-commit

I know that if we goto a github page like this:

https://github.com/probosckie/cssTreeShaking/commits?author=probosckie

we can get all the commits at a user level -> for a given repo. but it is only for master branch.

But how can we get all the commits by a user for a repo - across all branches?

Is there a git command for it or some github page?

Please help - i want to cherry-pick some commits i made today across few branches but i dont recall the branch names. It is only for 1 repo.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily view all commits by a specific author with `git log` or `gitk`, just pass [`--all`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---all) as refspec and then filter for author with `--author=authorname`:

```
git log --oneline --author=probosckie --all
gitk --author=probosckie --all
```

Comment: Yep, that seems the better solution.

Answer (score 0):

A specific command is not crossing my mind, but you could maybe create a BASH script which will do a checkout to a desired branch, followed by doing a `git log` and finally a `grep <username>` where `<username>` is the one you want to search for.

Something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

git checkout $1
git log | grep '<username>'
```